# how i can figuring the highest number in my array...visual basic

Tags: vb.net, vba

how i can figure the highest number in my array...below is the code...can someone help me to solve my problems...n i wan to show the result in the label from the other windows form....thank u... :

```
Public Class Frm2
    Public Parties(9) As String
    Public Votes(9) As String

    Dim vote As Integer
        Dim Party As String


        Party = TParty.Text
        vote = TVote.Text



     For I As Integer = 0 To Parties.Length - 1
            If Parties(I) = "" Then
                Parties(I) = TParty.Text()

                For J As Integer = 0 To Votes.Length - 1
                    If Votes(J) = "" Then
                        Votes(J) = TVote.Text()
                        MsgBox(TParty.Text & TVote.Text & "  votes")
                        TParty.Clear()
                        TVote.Clear()

                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next J
            End If
        Next

        MsgBox("you can vote now")
```

Comment: Are you storing numbers as text? Consider using `Votes() As Integer`.

Comment: I do not see where `TParty` or `TVote` is assigned.

Comment: Is this code in VBA or in VB.NET?

Comment: @dee after your comment, it actually seems to me it is in VB.NET. Which is important to make sure, because in that case the user will not be able to use `WorksheetFunction.Max(Votes)`

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, good point. In that case, it's as easy as `Votes.Max`.

Comment: Exactly @DougGlancy. I suggest you to add this info to your answer, it will be perfect in both cases then and surely being marked if user will ever come back to the thread.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, will do.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an algorithm to find the highest number into an array (let's say `Votes`), the classic is coming from the so-called *Bubble Sort*:

```
Dim max As Long 'change the type accordingly, for example if votes are 1-10 then Integer is better
max = Votes(0) 'set the first vote as the max
For j = 1 To Votes.Length - 1
    If Votes(j) >= max Then max = Votes(j) 'if another element is larger, then it is the max
Next j
```

Now the variable `max` stores the highest value of the array `Votes`, that you can show anywhere as, for example, in `MyForm.MyLabel.Text = max`. More useful info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Please note that now you declare `Public Votes(9) As String`, which means they are strings so not usable as numbers. You might want to declare them with a different data type, or use the `CInt()` method to convert strings in integers as suggested by ja72.

Comment: Or use `CInt()` to convert string into integer.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this would only work with a `Variant` array, but in quick testing it seems to work with an array of `Longs` as well:

```
Dim Votes(9) as Long    
Dim Max As Long
Max=WorksheetFunction.Max(Votes)
```

Note that, as Matteo says, you should change Votes() to an array of numeric types. I'd use `Long`, as it's a native VBA type.

EDIT: As noted by Dee, the code in this question is actually VB.Net. I added that as a tag. In VBA the solution would be even simpler, as `Max` is an array property:

```
Max=Votes.Max
```

(I suppose it would be a good idea to change the variable name from "Max".)

Comment: Please note that this method is not only easier to "write", but also and especially more efficient because it uses a built-in function instead of looping through the elements. I personally can only upvote this, but if I were you I'd pick this way instead.